# angular checkboxes with 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a template:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let cargo of cargos" class="cont-mat">
    /*...*/
<form [formGroup]="cargoSignupForm" (submit)="onSignupForCargo(cargo.id)" *ngIf="!isLoading">
                                          <p>Odaberite kamione s kojima želite izvršiti prijevoz - Težina robe: {{cargo.weight}} kg</p>
                                          <div *ngFor="let truck of (trucksByCargoId.get(cargo.id))">
                                            <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(truck._id, $event.target.checked, cargo.id)">{{truck.regNumber}}
                                          </div>
                                          <input type="submit" value="GO" class="button-basic">
                                        </form>
```

and 2 component functions:

```
truckFormArray = [[]];

ngOnInit() {
/*...*/
    this.cargoSignupForm = new FormGroup({
            trucksId: this.fb.array([])
          });
/*...*/
}

onChange(truckId: string, isChecked: boolean, cargoId: string) {
    this.truckFormArray[cargoId] = <FormArray>this.cargoSignupForm.controls.trucksId;
    if (isChecked) {
      this.truckFormArray[cargoId].push(new FormControl(truckId));
    } else {
      let index = this.truckFormArray[cargoId].controls.findIndex(x => x.value == truckId)
      this.truckFormArray[cargoId].removeAt(index);
    }
  }

  onSignupForCargo(cargoId: string) {
      console.log(this.truckFormArray[cargoId]);
  }
```

I just want to `console_log(this.truckFormArray[cargoId])`. There must be different `truckFormArray` for every `cargoId`. With that solution I'm getting `trucksFormArray` from previus `cargoId` checkboxes also. I hope you understand what I mean. Somewhere is a small mistake, but also if you think there is a better solution to do that you are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you create a woring demo in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## truckFormArray should be an object

It is safe to assume that `cargoId` is not a sequentially increasing number starting from 0, hence there is no sense in declaring it as an array, declare it as an object instead:

```
truckFormArray = {};
```

**Reason**: Arrays in Javascript are always indexed by numbers starting from 0 and increasing sequentially until the last index.

## truckFormArray is not a data member of the instance of your object

Since it is not initialized as `this.truckFormArray`, you do not have the `this` in front of it. So change all occurrences of `this.truckFormArray` to `truckFormArray`.

**Reason**: You will always need to be consistent when you refer to your resources.

## Initializing `truckFormArray`

You have

```
this.truckFormArray[cargoId] = <FormArray>this.cargoSignupForm.controls.trucksId;
```

and it seems to be incorrect. Your `trucksId` seems to be a number and you try to assign it to a resource which is treated as an array, so there is a type discrepancy. If you want to store each `trucksId` into an array identified by the cargo that is present on the trucks, then you need to do a push, but only if the checkbox is checked. So, instead of the above, you will need something like this:

```
if (!truckFormArray[cargoId]) {
    //Here I created a JS array for the sake of simplicity, but you can
    //create a FormArray instance instead if that's more helpful for you
    this.truckFormArray[cargoId] = [];
}
```

**Reason**: if the array you need to refer to does not exist yet, then you need to create it.

## Summary

You will need to

- fix the initialization of `truckFormArray`
- ensure that you refer it consistently with the way it is defined
- initialize each of its cargo array when needed